# Shared Data Members that are unique to inheritance branches?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have the situation below. Is there a simple way to design this so that the data member sample is shared among all instantiations of ChildClass1 and a separate instance of it is shared with all instances of ChildClass2?

```
abstract class BaseClass{
int sample = 0;
}

class ChildClass1: BaseClass{
}

class ChildClass2: BaseClass{
}
```

I'm hoping to produce the following

```
ChildClass1 a = new ChildClass1();
ChildClass1 b = new ChildClass1();
ChildClass2 c = new ChildClass2(); 

a.sample = 10;

//a.sample = 10, b.sample = 10, c.sample = 0
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I smell some bad design here.  Can you elaborate *why* you wish to do this?

Comment: Do you want `static` (`shared` in VB.Net)? But I agree, this smells like a bad idea...

Comment: @Corak, no - he wants to have a base-class member (`sample`), and have it behave differently depending on what *inherits* the base class...  :/

Comment: Oh, got it. So both `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` have a `private static int mSample` and override `BaseClass.Sample` by getting/setting the static `mSample`... should work? (untested)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this does, what you want:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract int Sample { get; set; }
}  

public class ChildClass1 : BaseClass
{
    private static int mSample = 0;
    public override int Sample 
    { 
        get { return mSample; }
        set { mSample = value; }
    }
}

public class ChildClass2 : BaseClass
{
    private static int mSample = 0;
    public override int Sample 
    { 
        get { return mSample; }
        set { mSample = value; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new ChildClass1();
        var b = new ChildClass1();
        var c = new ChildClass2();

        a.Sample = 10;

        Console.WriteLine(a.Sample); // 10
        Console.WriteLine(b.Sample); // 10
        Console.WriteLine(c.Sample); // 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, I think there is an inherent flaw in your design, but for the sake of providing an answer, you could achieve it like this:

```
abstract class BaseClass<TDERIVED>
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, int> sampleDictionary_ = new Dictionary<Type, int>();

    public BaseClass()
    {
    }   // eo ctor


    public int Sample
    {
        get
        {
            return sampleDictionary_.ContainsKey(typeof(TDERIVED)) ? sampleDictionary_[typeof(TDERIVED)] : 0;
        }
        set
        {
            sampleDictionary_[typeof(TDERIVED)] = value;
        }
    }
}

class ChildClass1 : BaseClass<ChildClass1>
{
}

class ChildClass2 : BaseClass<ChildClass2>
{
}
```

This has the added advantage that if you add any other Child classes, they will get their own version of the response.  Note that this is *not* thread-safe, and so if you do choose this solution and want to use it in a multi-threaded environment, you might want to put some thread-safety code in place.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the [singleton pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Create a class as a singleton to hold the shared data. Then have all three classes reference the singleton.